# Python URL get middle string

Tags: python

How to get this string "534641" (this value is dynamic, can be 6,5,4 digits)? How to find "-" before "534641"?

```
import re

string = "http://www.test.com.my/white-red-gift-perfume-powerbank-yellow-534641.html?ff=1\u0026s=Ebsr"
m = re.search('-(.+?).html', string).group(1)
print (m)
```

https://repl.it/JSxp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Since what you want is only digits, you could use `\d` to capture only digits:

```
>>> m = re.search('-(\d+).html', string).group(1)
>>> print (m)
534641
```

Another way would be to tell 'all characters excepts `-`':

```
>>> m = re.search('-([^-]+).html', string).group(1)
>>> print (m)
534641
```

For more info, see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html).

Some quick notes: the `.html` should be `\.html`, avoid using names such as 'string', 'list' that are used by python. It could go wrong without knowing why.

Comment: awesome answer, will mark this as answer, thanks for the help +1

Answer (score 1):

You already have the number at the end. Just split on the dashes using:

```
m = re.search('-(.+?).html', string).group(1).split("-")
# last element in m is the number you are looking for
print (m[-1])
```